# How to explode an array of strings and store results in another array (php)

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-extraction

Have text file in format:

```
(400, 530); 6.9; 5.7; 5.0;//------> continues for 100 values.

(500, 530); 7.9; 5.1; 5.0;

(600, 530); 6.7; 6.7; 7.2;
```

Code:

```
<?php
$file="./Speed10.asc";
$document=file_get_contents($file);
$rows = explode ('(', $document); //splits document into rows

foreach ($rows as &$rowvalue) {
     explode (';', $rowvalue);<----- How to assign each of these to member 
                                     of an array??
  }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to create 2D array, by splitting first into rows, then by element split by ';'

Comment: what are your expecting output???

Comment: is this `$result[] = explode (';', $rowvalue);`  ok

Comment: expected output would be [1][0]: (400, 530);  [1][1]: 6.9;   [1][2]: 5.7;        [1][3]: 5.0;     etc.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Thank you for your answer, would i be correct in saying that would create multiple versions of $result[] ? Avoiding that is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Input:

```
$document='(400, 530); 6.9; 5.7; 5.0; ...
(500, 530); 7.9; 5.1; 5.0; ...
(600, 530); 6.7; 6.7; 7.2; ...';
```

Method #1 (values without semi-colons stored in array):

```
foreach(explode("\r\n",$document) as $row){   // split the content by return then newline
    $result[]=explode("; ",$row);             // split each row by semi-colon then space
}
var_export($result);
/* Output:
    [
        ['(400, 530)','6.9','5.7','5.0','...'],
        ['(500, 530)','7.9','5.1','5.0','...'],
        ['(600, 530)','6.7','6.7','7.2','...']
    ]
) */
```

Method #2 (values with semi-colons stored in array):

```
foreach(explode("\r\n",$document) as $row){    // split the content by return then newline
    $result[]=preg_split('/(?<!,) /',$row);    // split each row by space not preceeded by comma
}
var_export($result);
/* Output:
    [
        ['(400, 530);','6.9;','5.7;','5.0;','...'],
        ['(500, 530);','7.9;','5.1;','5.0;','...'],
        ['(600, 530);','6.7;','6.7;','7.2;','...']
    ]
) */
```

Here is [demo of both methods](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88b5eaead7f50bec6b50934a3e49a1ce7537a3f9).

Keep in mind I am only focusing on the string splitting inside the loop.  Kris' advice on file handling is advisable.

Depending on your environment, you may need to adjust the first explode by removing `\r` or similar.